# Can I Redirect mis-addressed message on outgoing MSMQ?

Tags: wcf, msmq

I have a bunch of message on an outgoing MSMQ that have been addressed incorrectly due to a typo.  They are stuck on the outgoing queue since the box they have been directed at does not exist.

The name of the queue is of the form

DIRECT=OS:foo\private$\MyQueue and is in state Waiting to connect

and I want to send to

DIRECT=OS:bar\private$\MyQueue

Will an entry in the hosts file suffice, or if not is there any other way that I can go this?  I don't want to have to create a server called and a process that recieves the messages and forwards them on to the correct server if at all possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modan,

I experienced something similar years ago and the only way I could find was to setup the box and Q (in a VM) and forward them to correct queue.  Maybe you can delete and resend the messages with the fix?  Is that possible?  Unfortunately don't think there's a good way around this.

-Bryan

Answer (score 1):

I tried the idea I suggested above of adding the incorrect entry into the Hosts file with the correct IP address.  This caused the messages to get dispatched to the remote computer, but I think WCF dropped them as they didn't have the correct endpoint adress.

Not recommended if you don't want to lose the messages!  Fortunately for me these were not critical, so it was worth a try.

Oh well